# Use list entries as keys for dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, dictionary

I have a

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

telling me all of the things I should find in some input data.  I'd like to convert this into a

```
Dictionary<string, bool> myDict = Dictionary<string, bool>();
```

where the dictionary keys are the same as the list entries, and all the values are false.  I'll then run over the data, and update the dictionary value when I find the elements.

This seems simple, but

```
Dictionary<string, bool> myDict = myList.ToDictionary<string, bool>(x => false);
```

doesn't work because of an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Dictionary<bool, string>` to `Dictionary<string, bool>`

Comment: "doesn't work" => while it's clear to an expert what the problem is, the question could certainly include the actual error.

Comment: siride - indeed, thanks.

Comment: the downvotes were probably because of the phrase "it doesn't work" without further information. You've since fixed that, but people probably didn't come back to remove their downvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
var dict = myList.ToDictionary(s => s, s => false);
```

The overload that you were using will create a `Dictionary<bool, string>`, with key being bool and value the string values from the list. ( And having bool as key will mean, you can have only two entries ;)

Also, you rarely need to specify the type parameters like `<string, bool>` to methods explcitly, as they can be inferred, and you can use `var` for variables, like done above.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) and specify false as the value.

```
myDict  = myList.ToDictionary(r=> r, r=> false);
```

The code you are using will give you `Dictionary<bool,string>`, if you look in the intellisense then:

[image]

and hence the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

Comment: Please make a note of what the *actual* problem is instead of just dumping code.

Comment: @siride, "doesn't work" means what ?? - Here is the code in the answer that should **WORK**

Comment: but the problem is that the OP failed to use the right overload to set both key and value, and that should be explained.

Comment: @siride, Is the code in the answer is wrong ? why the downvote ?

Comment: I already explained. I don't think that just dumping correct code is a good answer by itself. manojlds's answer above actually explains the problem in addition to giving correct code.

Comment: @siride It may not be 100% helpful.. but it isn't incorrect. Why is a downvote warranted for that?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: downvote isn't just about whether it's technically correct. It's about quality. And I don't think this is a quality answer if it just dumps code and a link. Is that what we want this site to be filled with?

Comment: @siride, I have edited my answer with all the possible details

Comment: @siride, giving downvote is upto you , but if you just hover over the `downvote` then you will see `This answer is not useful` which in this case is not true, yes may be its earlier form didn't provide all the information but it would solve the OP's problem

Comment: @Habib: it wasn't useful. It did directly solve the OPs problem, but this site isn't just about that. It's about building a repository of questions and answers that people will find on Google and be able to apply to their particular problems.